# linq ambiguity on where and select

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, c#-4.0, lambda

Today I ran into an issue with LINQ to objects (not SQL) that popped up due to a typo. I had a `.Select` one place and a `.Where` in another place. I was expecting same result but they are showing different numbers. Assume `somelist` has 10 elements with all elements having `qty` = `0`

```
//returns 10 - basically count of all rows. I am expecting 0
 somelist.Select(p => p.qty > 0).Count() 

//returns 0 - the correct count
 somelist.Where(p => p.qty > 0).Count()
```

if both select and where return `IEnumerable<T>` then why the ambiguity? Thank you.

Comment: thx everyone for that linq 101 update.

Comment: It's one of those interesting naming issues, c# is trying to be syntactically like sql (which sql is suggesting you select columns), but the name `Select`, especially if you put in a predicate, can read like you to select only said items that pass, infact in ruby and smalltalk that's what the the `select` method does.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) is a projection, so what you get is the expression `p.qty > 0` evaluated for each element in `somelist`. i.e. lots of true/false values (the same number as your original list). So when you do `Count` on it, you get the same number. If you look the select will return `IEnumerable<bool>` (because the type of `p.qty > 0` is a bool).

[`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) filters the results so count runs on the filtered list, and give you the expected results. The type of this is an `IEnumerable<TypeOfElementInOriginalList>`.

Note you can also do: `somelist.Count(p => p.qty > 0)` because Count has an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) that accepts a predicate to filter by.

Answer (score 2):

The first query gives the same as `somelist.Count()`. It's just the number of elements in the sequence. The call to `Select` *projects* each object, but the number of objects remains the same.

The second query gives the number of elements that fulfil the predicate, which is a potentially lower number. The call to `Where` *filters* objects from the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The first query returns an IEnumerable of booleans.

The second query only returns elements in the original that match the boolean expression.

Answer (score 0):

The first statement creates an `IEnumerable` of bools: is the `qty` field > 0. Since there are 10 records, you get 10 bools.

The second return an IEnumerable filtered over the condition.